# Insert tagged entry into sqlite the Right Way

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have tagged entries where the entries are in one table, the tags are in another, and then there's a table that maps entries to tags. I'm using sqlite and here's some example code

```sql
CREATE TABLE Entry (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Tags (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  tag TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TagMap (
  entry INTEGER NOT NULL,
  tag INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (entry) REFERENCES Entry(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tag) REFERENCES Tags(id),
  UNIQUE (entry, tag)
);
```

Right now the data is stored in json like this:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Thing",
        "tags": ["a", "b", "c"]
    },
    ...
]
```

The best way I can think to do this from a script is to

1. Gather all the tags and insert them.
2. Insert all the names.
3. Query all the tags to get their id's.
4. Query all the names to get their id's
5. In python/bash change all the "tags" and "names" fields in the json to their respective id's
6. Insert the id's and tags into TagMap

Instead of doing all that I would like to make a single expression that:

1. Add's the tags if they aren't already there and returns the id's (I have sqlite >=3.35 so I can use RETURNING)
2. Add's the name to Entry and returns the id
3. Add's the entry id and tag id's to TagMap.

I like the single expression because if anything goes wrong it's all dropped, I imagine there's optimizations that can be made, if later on down the line I just add one at a time I don't have to query every single tag, and it *seems* elegant and Right.

Keep in mind I have only a few days of SQL experience so If you are sitting there thinking, "My 5 years of SQL experience tells me this is dumb and you should just do it in code" please tell me.

If you have any better way of structuring this please tell me.

PS: I will eventually throw this into sqlalchemy so bonus points if you want to tell me how to do that part as well.

Comment: There is no single statement to insert in to more than one table. Instead, you wrap multiple statements within a Transaction. If any part of the transaction fails, the whole transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: *Right now the data is stored in json...* where are they stored? You mention only 3 tables in your question.

Comment: @forpas I'm migrating data from json to sqlite. So right now all the data is in json and there is nothing in sqlite.

Comment: @MatBailie So should I do the first thing I suggested (six steps) in one transaction or should I do a bunch of transactions with the second thing that I suggested (three steps)?

Comment: *all the data is in json* where? Is it a text file? Where are the jsons stored?

Comment: @forpas yeah it's a text file. Why? Where else could it have been stored?

Comment: They could be imported in another SQLite table so that the process could be done with sql code.